# Запуск web приложения на Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, war

Не запускается веб приложение на локальной машине. Закидывал war в webapps, распаковывал в ROOT - одно и то же. В логах ошибок нет. Из IDE работает нормально.

Запускал сервер из панели Monitor Tomcat - варник распаковывался, и вроде все шло без ошибок. Попробовал запустить через `startup.bat`, и повалились исключения:

```
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\logs\catalina.2018-05-26.log (Отказано в доступе)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:504)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:176)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:82)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:601)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:538)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:336)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\logs\localhost.2018-05-26.log (Отказано в доступе)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:504)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:176)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:82)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:601)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:538)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:336)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\logs\manager.2018-05-26.log (Отказано в доступе)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:504)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:176)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:82)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:601)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:538)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:336)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\logs\host-manager.2018-05-26.log (Отказано в доступе)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:504)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:176)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:82)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:601)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:538)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:336)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
26-May-2018 19:14:43.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.30
26-May-2018 19:14:43.092 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 3 2018 20:04:09 UTC
26-May-2018 19:14:43.095 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.30.0
26-May-2018 19:14:43.096 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
26-May-2018 19:14:43.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
26-May-2018 19:14:43.098 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
26-May-2018 19:14:43.100 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
26-May-2018 19:14:43.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
26-May-2018 19:14:43.102 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
26-May-2018 19:14:43.103 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
26-May-2018 19:14:43.109 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
26-May-2018 19:14:43.111 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\logging.properties
26-May-2018 19:14:43.112 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
26-May-2018 19:14:43.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
26-May-2018 19:14:43.114 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
26-May-2018 19:14:43.116 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
26-May-2018 19:14:43.117 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
26-May-2018 19:14:43.123 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
26-May-2018 19:14:43.127 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open Failed to open access log file [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\logs\localhost_access_log.2018-05-26.txt]
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\logs\localhost_access_log.2018-05-26.txt (╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄєях)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open(AccessLogValve.java:651)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.startInternal(AccessLogValve.java:685)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:955)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

26-May-2018 19:14:43.921 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\dict.war]
26-May-2018 19:14:43.989 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context [/dict]
 java.io.IOException: Unable to create the directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\dict]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:738)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1856)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

26-May-2018 19:14:57.750 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan JAR [war:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.5/webapps/dict.war*/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar] from /WEB-INF/lib
 java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp\jar_cache6170217854763631368.tmp
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:138)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempFile(TempFileHelper.java:161)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Files.java:897)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:218)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:216)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:215)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:71)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldResourcePath.openStream(TldResourcePath.java:126)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.parse(TldParser.java:61)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.parseTld(TldScanner.java:279)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan(TldScanner.java:313)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:378)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:191)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5229)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1856)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

26-May-2018 19:14:57.996 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan JAR [war:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.5/webapps/dict.war*/WEB-INF/lib/standard-1.1.2.jar] from /WEB-INF/lib
 java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp\jar_cache5266195792821730232.tmp
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)     at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:138)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempFile(TempFileHelper.java:161)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Files.java:897)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:218)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:216)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:215)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:71)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldResourcePath.openStream(TldResourcePath.java:126)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.parse(TldParser.java:61)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.parseTld(TldScanner.java:279)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan(TldScanner.java:313)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:378)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:191)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5229)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1856)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

26-May-2018 19:14:58.011 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
26-May-2018 19:14:58.152 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\dict.war] has finished in [14,230] ms
26-May-2018 19:14:58.154 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs]
26-May-2018 19:14:58.213 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs] has finished in [59] ms
26-May-2018 19:14:58.218 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager]
26-May-2018 19:14:58.303 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager] has finished in [85] ms
26-May-2018 19:14:58.305 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT]
26-May-2018 19:14:59.488 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
26-May-2018 19:14:59.554 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [1,248] ms
26-May-2018 19:14:59.574 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-May-2018 19:14:59.597 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-May-2018 19:14:59.603 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 15810 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфигурации IDE я менял порт на 2323 и по привычке заходил на него. Через 8080 все заработало

Answer (score 2):

1. Создаем папку

   ```
   /opt/TomcatFolder/conf/Catalina/localhost/
   ```
2. в этом каталоге создаем файл `ROOT.xml`, в нем пишем:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Context path="" docBase="/opt/TomcatFolder/myapps/myapp.war" />
   ```
3. Создаем каталог

   ```
   /opt/TomcatFolder/myapps/
   ```
4. Копируем варник `myapp.war` в этот каталог, если он там есть - переписываем. С каждой перезаписью этого варника `Tomcat` будет перезаливать приложение в корень сервера.

Comment: Знаю, что надо было ставить линукс, но у меня винда